# Eclipse Alt+Shift+J to insert the file comment, how?

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

Using Alt+Shift+J in eclipse should insert a comment template related to the element designated by the cursor, like a field, method or class. There are several descriptions on the net where exactly to put the curser to designate the targeted element.

Yet I cannot get this working for the file comment, which is a comment that preceedes any code at the top of the file. Whatever I tried, in particular putting the cursor at the very beginning of the file, or the very end, I either get a class comment or an error message that I am not targeting any element.

Does inserting the file comment template with Alt+Shift+J work for anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The file comment template for java only works on new files.  There are several "copyright" plugins for eclipse that are designed to add comment templates to the top of existing files.

There is a nice java documentation plugin that may also work for you:
http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The default command mapped to Alt+Shift+J is "Add Javadoc Comment". Based on that, it makes sense to me that you aren't getting a file level comment, since [Javadoc comments "must preceed a class, field, constructor, or method declaration"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).

The default key bindings appear to indicate that Ctrl+Shift+/ can be used to add a block comment and Ctrl+Shift+\ can be used to remove a block comment. However, I'm not getting much luck with getting them to work at the top of a file. I am able to use Ctrl+/ to insert a single line comment.